# python search and replace xml file, ignoring the node the tag exists

Tags: python, xml, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a list of values (say a txt file), that I need to spot in an XML file, and replace these values, with their equivalent new ones, found in another txt file. What I have managed, is read the xml line by line and replace:

```
for line in open(template_file_name,'r'):
  output_line = line
  output_line = string.replace(output_line, placeholder, value)
  print output_line
```

Looking at how this could be achieved with a more efficient way,

Below is the XML I will be using:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <sample>
    <a>
      <id>Value_to_search_for</id>
      <class />
      <gender />
    </a>
  </sample>
```

I want to write a Python script which will search for tag 'id' and replace the value "Value_to_search_for" with "Replacement_value".

However the nesting of the above XML can change. So I want to make a generalized script that will search for the tag 'id' independently of its exact position.

Comment: Would you consider using an xml parser, like for example lxml.ElementTree?

Comment: yes, i have tried, but i cannot get rid of the part that i specifically provide the path. So i need something, that would be oath agnostic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from lxml import etree as et


def replace_tag_text_from_xml_file(xml_file_path,xpath,search_str,replacement_str):
    root = et.parse(xml_file_path)

    id_els = root.iterfind(xpath)

    for id_el in id_els:
        id_el.text = id_el.text.replace(search_str, replacement_str)

    return et.tostring(root)


print replace_tag_text_from_xml_file('./test.xml', './/id', 'Value_to_search_for', 'Replacement_value')
```

Comment: the above looks closer to what i try to do, perhaps have as a parameter the xml file, and the values to search for and replace with

Comment: @Toled You mean parameters of a function? Please, check the updated answer.

Comment: exactly, and also have the Value_to_search_for, and Replacement_value, in two txt files, filea.txt, fileb.txt, for having in a per line basis, the Value_to_search_for, and the Replacement_value

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
placeholder = "Value_to_search_for"
new_value = "New_Value"


for line in open("yourfile.xml"):
    output_line = line

    if "<id>" in line:
        beginning_index = line.index("<id>")
        end_index = line.index("</id>")+5       # 5 = The number of characters in '</id>'
        output_line = line
        output_line = output_line[beginning_index:end_index].replace(placeholder, new_value)

    print (output_line)
```

It finds the indexes of the beginning and the end of the values within the tags 'id' and it replaces what is inside with your new value.